# Decrypt a password in MudOS LPC

Tags: encryption, passwords

In LPC, it use `crypt()` to encrypt the password.

How can I decrypt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is based on Unix's `crypt`, despite it's name suggesting "encrypt" it's actually a one-way hash function and it intentionally has no reverse (decryption). If the password is reasonably simple, then [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) is a nice password cracker, but it can take a very long time if the password is not trivial.

Answer (score 2):

MudOS (now Fluff OS! https://www.fluffos.info/ ) uses a one-way hashing algorithm, but it's not a very strong one (or was historically). A lot of the mudlibs (the libraries that contain the LPC and the calls to hashing the passwords) furthermore had security issues where the salts were not random (or random enough), so they may be easier to break than normal.

Some MUDs even used the password itself as salt so for some hashed passwords you had the first part of the password actually be the first letters of the real password. Take a good close look at how they were salted and you may have an easier time decrypting them.

Otherwise, I suggest looking at the tool suggested by Rob.